# Different Message Board Portlet on different page in Liferay 5.2.3

Tags: liferay

Is it possible to implement different Message board portlet on different page in Liferay 5.2.3. But now if I am adding Message Board on two pages same posts are coming. I want these to be totally separate from each other. Can anyone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recall having scope content in 5.2.3 Liferay 6 does support page scoped content, so you can have different MB or blogs or wiki portlet on different pages of same community/org.

To check if scoping is supported in Liferay 5.2.3, Add MessageBoard portlet on a page. Click on Configuration(Its under look and feel icon of the portlet) and see if you have Scope tab. If you have Scope tab then, Liferay 5.2.3 supports scoping. Click on Scope tab. Select the current layout scope and click on save.

If you dont see Scope tab in Configuration option of the portlet, then it can confirmed that Liferay 5.2.3 does not support the feature you are looking for and you have to upgrade to Liferay 6

Comment: The scope options is available in Liferay 5.2.3 under configuration and its working exactly like what I want. Thanks a lot Sandeep. :)

Comment: If it helped you out, then can you please mark it as answer :)